# ' ' object is not iterable. Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the get() to display individual items.

Models:

```
class JoinGroup(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    details= models.TextField()
    travelers_that_have_booked=models.FloatField()
    price1=models.FloatField()
    price2=models.FloatField()
    price3=models.FloatField()
    price4=models.FloatField()
    price5=models.FloatField()
    price6=models.FloatField()
    price7=models.FloatField()
    image1=models.ImageField()
    image2=models.ImageField()
    image3=models.ImageField()
    image4=models.ImageField()
    image5=models.ImageField()
    image6=models.ImageField()
    image7=models.ImageField()
    accomodation=(
        ('budget'),
        ( 'standard')

    )
    itinerary= models.TextField()
    created_on=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    bookbefore=models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views:

```
def single(request, id):

    singlegroup = get_object_or_404(JoinGroup, id=id)

    return render(request, 'joingroup/single.html', {"singlegroup": singlegroup})
```

error:

```
'JoinGroup' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. Where are you iterating it? In the template? If so you need to show that code too.

Comment: In your template you probably write `{% for foo in singlegroup %}`, but `singlegroup` is a `JoinGroup` *object*, not a queryset of  `JoinGroup`s.

Comment: Lemmi post it..

Comment: template:

    {% for sgs in singlegroup %}
                <section>

                  <h3 class="fw-md mb-1">{{sgs.title}}</h3>
                  <ul class="hotel-title mb-3"> ....{% endfor %}

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem so what should i change?

Answer (score 2):

Here `singlegroup` is *not* a `QuerySet`, it is a `JoinGroup` object, so unless you made the object iterable (well the error indicates you did not), you can not iterate over it.

In your template, you write:

```
{% for sgs in singlegroup %}
<section><h3 class="fw-md mb-1">{{sgs.title}}</h3>
<ul class="hotel-title mb-3"> ....</ul&>lt;/section>
{% endfor %}
```

But this does not make much sense, since you fetched a *single* `JoinGroup` object, you thus can only render that single object. You can rewrite the template to:

```
<section><h3 class="fw-md mb-1">{{ singlegroup.title }}</h3>
<ul class="hotel-title mb-3"> ....</ul></section>
```

But based on the template, it is possible that this is more a "conceptual error"/"design error".

Comment: ..thanks so much. It works..funny enough, i never realized that before. Thanks again.